# Change colour of pattern file

Tags: adobe-fireworks, patterns, adobe-photoshop-elements

Can Photoshop pattern files be used so that the colours in the pattern are changed?

If so, can you tell me how I do this with [this pattern file](http://basstar.deviantart.com/art/Birthday-Special-91848568) in Photoshop Elements and/or Adobe Fireworks? (I don't have Adobe Photoshop).

I'd like to change the colour to hot pink pattern on a black background, for instance.

Comment: ..You need Adobe Photoshop first. How would you do it otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is in Firework to use LIVE FILTERS:
- click on the bitmap
- in the Properties panel, select Filters -> Adjust Colors -> Color Fill
- Select the color you want, and you're done

Answer (score 1):

What Carol was alluding to is, since the file is a Photoshop .pat file, you must have photoshop to open the file.

The actual pattern is simply a black tile. I've attached a transparent PNG of the tile here. You could simply grab the tile and recreate a pattern in Fireworks or Elements.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I can use this file as a pattern in Fireworks, but without converting it to a vector using 3rd party software I am unable to find a way to change it's color.

Comment: Can the colour be changed using Photoshop?  If not, that seems like a limiting use for pattern files.

Comment: I'm really not an Elements or Fireworks user. I know you could simply do a color overlay in Photoshop. Perhaps Elements or Fireworks has a feature similar to that.

Comment: Thanks Scott, there is color overlay available in Elements.  The trick is working out how to change both the background and foreground of the pattern.  I can do an overlay but it only changes the background color from transparent to a color.  I can't change the color of the black pattern.

Comment: The way I'd change the black in Fireworks is to stick a solid rectangle over the whole thing of the colour you want, then change its blend mode to 'Lighten'. To do this, go to Layers on the right with the rectangle selected, and change 'Normal' to 'Lighten' in the drop down. Then save as a Flattened PNG to fix the colour change. The same trick should work in Elements too, but I don't use Elements so can't check.

Comment: @yisela -- Okay I'll expend extra effort pointing out any gramatical errors I ever see you make.